# Restrict file access in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, servlets, security, file-security

There is a serious security issue in our product which runs on apache tomcat server listening on ports 80 and 443. The routing of incoming HTTP/HTTPS  packets on these ports is configured by our product classes, which fails to ensure that each requested URL refers to a file that is both located within the web root of the server and is of a type that is allowed to be served.

In particular, packets that match '/error/*' in the url  are configured to use the 'docroot' folder as the document root for serving files. And so  paths which traverse out of the /error/ (i.e docroot) directory using URL encoded backslashes `%5C` can also be accessed and downloaded. For example a remote user can give an url like –

```
    https://MyDomain/error/..%5c..%5csettings.properties
```

to access the remote file settings.properties that is on the same level as docroot. We are trying to overcome this through firewall rules and network segmentation. But is there a setting in tomcat that can be used to prevent remote users from accessing files outside the project root folder. That would be very useful.

Comment: Even if there is some filtering option that we can prevent access to file types like *.txt, *.properties other than the file path, even that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict direct URL access to some files, put them under WEB-INF directory.

Quote from here (note: *the below URL is currently unavalable*):
http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/web-application-directory-structure.html

> Root directory contains a directory named WEB-INF. Anything under the
> root directory excepting the WEB-INF directory is publicly
> available, and can be accessed by URL from browser.
>
> WEB-INF directory is a private area of the web application, **any files under WEB-INF
> directory cannot be accessed directly from browser by specifying the
> URL** like `http://somesite/WEB-INF/someresource.html`. Web container will
> not serve the content of this directory. However the content of the
> WEB-INF directory is accessible by the classes within the application.
> So if there are any resources like JSPs or HTML document that you
> don’t wish to be accessible directly from web browser, you should
> place it under WEB-INF directory.

Comment: @Gawey The "servletworld.com" website seems to be not hosted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could be able to restrict access to your error folder using robots. and also you can map entry to error/* to the redirected page.

Encoding all requests and responses should solve the / -> %5c issue

Comment: Hi thanks for you help. But can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: Hello Mohammed..I would really appreciate if you could explain bit elaborately.

Comment: Hello I have created a text file called robots.txt inside the webapps/ROOT folder with below contents --  
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.txt

Comment: But still .txt files can be accessed and downloaded. Your help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any one to help me in this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you disallow .txt files? For your case i think the disallow statement has to be Disallow : /error/